# Como retornar a categoria mais predominante associada a um grupo?

Tags: r

Tenho um banco de dados, no qual a variável `a` é a variável de grupo e `b` uma variável com algumas categorias. Meu objetivo é, dentro de cada grupo de `a`, retornar o que mais aparece em `b`.

Considere o `dput`:

```
dataset=structure(list(a = c(500, 500, 500, 400, 400, 400, 300, 300, 
300), b = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("a", 
"b"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Resultado desejado:

```
  a  b
500  a
400  b
500  a
```

Além disso, seria útil retornar as contagens e porcentagens dessa predominância. Algo como:

```
a    b    count    percent
500  a    2        .66 #66%
400  b    2        .66 #66% 
500  a    2        .66 #66%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando o pacote `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
dataset %>% 
  group_by(a, b) %>% 
  summarise(count = n()) %>% 
  mutate(percent = count/sum(count)) %>% 
  filter(count == max(count))
```